# How to Print PDF file directly from node application?

Tags: node.js, pdf, printing

I am creating a pdf-document from HTML in my nodejs application with phantomjs. This works totally well so far. Now I want to directly print this file to a network printer. I am using the node-printer module and the printing itself works. However only in RAW format.

```
var format = 'RAW';
var printerName = '\\\\PRNTSRV\\Kyo Copy Printer';
var data = fs.readFileSync('./tmp/phantom.tmp.pdf');

printer.printDirect({
   data: data,
   printer: printerName,
   type: format,
   success: function(id) {
       console.log('printing done with id', id);
       res.json({
          success: true,
          message: 'printed at ' + printerName
       });
   },
   error: function(err) {
       console.log('error on printing: ' + err);
   }
});
```

Some of the printer understand it when they get send the pdf document as RAW, however a lot of our printer (especially the label printers where the system finally is needed) don't understand the PDF file formats, and I have to send them as EMF. I tried TEXT as well that did not work, so it all points to EMF.

I tried node-imagemagick and node-pdfium to convert the pdf to emf but I couldn't get both to run. Imagemagick produced empty documents and I did not get node-pdfium to compile. It breaks everytime while I use *npm install pdfium*. There is an open issue on the github page for this type of error, but no response since april, so I guess I've to find another alternative.

Now my question, how can I convert the PDF file to EMF format without using either imagemagick nor node-pdfium?

**UPDATE**

I am now generating a postscript file with ghostscript (pdf2ps) and try to send it as RAW to several printer, but this does not work either. I am generating the postscript like this, which works fine and produces a valid level2 postscript file:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec(
  '"' + config.gs_binary + '" ' 
  +  '-dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=ps2write '
  +  '-sOutputFile=' + outFile '
  +  inputFile
, function(err, stdout,stderr) {
    console.log(err, stdout, stderr);

    // continue with sending to printer with RAW and printer.printDirect and    
    // using the ps file instead of the pdf file...
  }
);
```

the content of the postscript file (excerpt)

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 216 111
%%HiResBoundingBox: 0 0 216.00 111.00
%%Creator: GPL Ghostscript 915 (ps2write)
%%LanguageLevel: 2
%%CreationDate: D:20151002103717+02'00'
%%Pages: 1
%%EndComments
%%BeginProlog
/DSC_OPDFREAD true def
/SetPageSize true def
/EPS2Write false def
currentdict/DSC_OPDFREAD known{
currentdict/DSC_OPDFREAD get
}{
false
}ifelse
10 dict begin

[...]
```

After sending the ps document as RAW to the printer, it still recognizes it but the results vary from printer to printer. e.g. they deny to print, they show a protocolerror or they print lots of pages of gibberish (gibberish => not the ps content as text).

**UPDATE 2**

Since I did not get the PostScript-files send by RAW to the printers at all I did another approach that worked (for now). I generate the pdf as usual and then send it to an external binary together with the printername that handles the printing part with `require('child_process').exec(...)`. Let's see when I will encounter the first limitations.

Comment: I'd look into ghostscript if I were you and also see if PostScript is an option for your printers, too. I can't vouch for any specify modules but ultimately they'll all probably shell out to a binary somewhere.

Comment: @ChrisHaas thank you for your suggestion. I tried it out, you can see my results in the edited "update" part of my question.

Comment: Hello, I'm currently having the same problem. I see you want to send it to label printers, I try to send a pdf to a POS printer. I couldnt get pdfium or imagemagick to work either , tried converting manually a pdf to EMF and try to print it, nothing either with RAW format or NT EMF 1.00x. How did you get it to work with this binary? Are you not printing with node anymore?

Comment: Yes I still do printing. A lot actually since it worked. The binary is an external program that is able to silently print pdf files. For example Foxit is such a software, but there are others as well. The procedure is as I described. I create the PDF file with phantomjs and then execute an external (binary) program with the pdf file path as argument (besides others) look at spawn module for nodejs how to execute external software. The binary returns a result (when it finished executing) and i can delete the temporary pdf file.

Comment: I wanted to do the same can you post your solution in detail, please?