# Printing a PDF file with Electron JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, printing, electron

I am trying to create an Electron JS app that has the purpose to print letter size PDFs.

This is my snippet of code for printing:

```
win = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 378, 
  height: 566, 
  show: true, 
  webPreferences: {
    webSecurity: false,
    plugins: true
  }
});

// load PDF
win.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/header1_X_BTR.pdf');

// if pdf is loaded start printing
win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
  win.webContents.print({silent: true, printBackground:true});
});
```

My issues are: if I have `print({silent:true})` my printer prints an empty page. If I have `print({silent:false})`, the printer prints in the same way as the screenshot, with headers, controls, etc.

[image]

I need a silent print of the PDF content, and I can't manage to do it for days. Did anyone experience the same thing with Electron?

Comment: Please upload your reproduction code on a `git` repository. With a reproduction, I can help you better.

Comment: @Noseratio Heyho, since Electronjs is very buggy thing above Nodejs, I would suggest to try the answer for ["how to print PDF in Nodejs app"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32889174/how-to-print-pdf-file-directly-from-node-application). You have to spawn the new child process on the background and try to use external tool (for what you have to check the platform of course like darwin vs win).

Comment: @boldnik, I think I covered those options in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51829830/1768303).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have already have the pdf file or you save the pdf before printing "I assuming it is", then you can grab the file location then you can use externals process to do the printing using `child_process`.

You can use `lp command` or [PDFtoPrinter](http://www.columbia.edu/~em36/pdftoprinter.html) for windows

```
const ch = require('os');

switch (process.platform) {
    case 'darwin':
    case 'linux':
        ch.exec(
            'lp ' + pdf.filename, (e) => {
                if (e) {
                    throw e;
                }
            });
        break;
    case 'win32':
        ch.exec(
            'ptp ' + pdf.filename, {
                windowsHide: true
            }, (e) => {
                if (e) {
                    throw e;
                }
            });
        break;
    default:
        throw new Error(
            'Platform not supported.'
        );
}
```

I hope it helps.

**Edit:**
You can also use SumatraPDF for windows https://github.com/sumatrapdfreader/sumatrapdf

Comment: `LPR` direct printing requires a PDF-enabled printer, most printers are not. SumatraPDF might be an option, although `PdfiumViewer` seems to be better positioned towards this task.

Comment: PDFtoPrinter requires installation of a 3rd party app which seems to require signing a bundle distribution license, same as Adobe Acrobat Reader.

Comment: @Noseratio yeah, but **the baseline is there to do a silent printing** the ```lp``` and ```ptp``` can be replaced by other command/software that you like, to do the printing, just spawn other process. And also I think on modern system now most of them use ```CUPS``` instead of ```LPR```, correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way to do this is to render the PDF pages to individual canvas elements on a page using PDF.js and then call print.

I fixed [this gist](https://gist.github.com/fcingolani/3300351) to use the PDF.js version (v1) it was designed for and its probably a good starting point.

This is essentially what the electron/chrome pdf viewer is doing but now you have full control over the layout!

```html
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/1.10.90/pdf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function renderPDF(url, canvasContainer, options) {
    var options = options || { scale: 1 };
        
    function renderPage(page) {
        var viewport = page.getViewport(options.scale);
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var renderContext = {
          canvasContext: ctx,
          viewport: viewport
        };
        
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;
        canvasContainer.appendChild(canvas);
        
        page.render(renderContext);
    }
    
    function renderPages(pdfDoc) {
        for(var num = 1; num <= pdfDoc.numPages; num++)
            pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(renderPage);
    }
    PDFJS.disableWorker = true;
    PDFJS.getDocument(url).then(renderPages);
}   
</script> 

<div id="holder"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
renderPDF('//cdn.mozilla.net/pdfjs/helloworld.pdf', document.getElementById('holder'));
</script>  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We use the electron `printToPdf` api and then use this to display a preview inline with our UI before saving to file or outputting to printer. It's super powerful and flexible.

Comment: For now, PDF.js solves the problem with rendering/previewing individual pages, but as to printing itself, it appears Electron (at the time of this posting) just lacks the proper printing APIs. E.g., you can't set paper size/landscape portrait mode etc. Moreover, when printing, PDF.js produces rasterized printouts - thanks to how HTML5 canvas work - unlike Chrome PDF Viewer.
So for now I think it'll be a combination of PDF.js (for UI in the Electron's Renderer process) and PDFium (for actual printing from the Main process).

Answer (score 5):

I'm facing the same issue. It appears the PDF printing to a printer is just not implemented in Electron, despite it's been requested since 2017. Here is another related question on SO and the feature request on GitHub:

- [Silent printing in electron](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46012272/1768303)
- [Support printing in native PDF rendering](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9029)

**One possible solution might be to use [Google PDFium](https://pdfium.googlesource.com/pdfium) and a wrapping [NodeJS library](https://github.com/tojocky/node-pdfium)** which appears to allow conversion from PDF to a set of EMFs, so the EMFs can be printed to a local/network printer, at least on Windows.

As another viable option, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41751184/1768303) provides a simple C# solution for PDF printing using [PdfiumViewer](https://github.com/pvginkel/PdfiumViewer), which is a PDFium wrapper library for .NET.

I'm sill looking at any other options. Utilizing a locally installed instance of Acrobat Reader for printing is not an acceptable solution for us.

---

**UPDATED.** For now, [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js) solves the problem with rendering/previewing individual pages, but as to printing itself, it appears Electron (at the time of this posting) just lacks the proper printing APIs. E.g., you can't set paper size/landscape portrait mode etc. Moreover, when printing, PDF.js produces rasterized printouts - thanks to how HTML5 canvas work - unlike how Chrome PDF Viewer does it. Here is [a discussion](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=15167717) of some other PDF.js shortcomings.

So for now I think we might go on with a combination of PDF.js (for UI in the Electron's Renderer process) and PDFium (for actual printing from the Main process).

Based on [Tim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51847907/1768303), here's a version of the PDF.js renderer using ES8 `async/await` (supported as of the current version of Electron):

```
async function renderPDF(url, canvasContainer, options) {
    options = options || { scale: 1 };

    async function renderPage(page) {
        let viewport = page.getViewport(options.scale);
        let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        let renderContext = {
            canvasContext: ctx,
            viewport: viewport
        };

        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;
        canvasContainer.appendChild(canvas);

        await page.render(renderContext);
    }

    let pdfDoc = await pdfjsLib.getDocument(url);

    for (let num = 1; num <= pdfDoc.numPages; num++)
    {
        if (num > 1)
        {
            // page separator
            canvasContainer.appendChild(document.createElement('hr'));
        }
        let page = await pdfDoc.getPage(num);
        await renderPage(page);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since your are using `contents.print([options], [callback])` I will assume that you want to print on paper and not on your Disk.

---

The answer to your issue is simple. It is the event you are listening on which is causing the error. So if you simply do this:

```
  winObject.webContents.on('did-frame-finish-load', () => {
    setTimeout(() => {winObject.webContents.print({silent: true, printBackground:true})}, 3000);
  });
```

everything will work fine if the default printer is the right one. I did test this and it will do its job more or less. You can change my event to whatever event you like, the important part is the waiting with setTimeout. The PDF you are trying to print is simply not available in the frame when using `silent:true`.

However let me get into detail here a little bit to make things clear:

Electron will load Files or URLs into a created window (`BrowserWindow`) which is bound to events. The problem is that every event "can" behave differently on different systems.
We have to live with that and cannot change this easily. But knowing this will help improve the development of custom Apps.

If you load urls or htmls everything will work without setting any custom options. Using PDFs as source we have to use this:

```
import electron, { BrowserWindow } from 'electron';
const win = new BrowserWindow({
  // @NOTE I did keep the standard options out of this.
  webPreferences: { // You need this options to load pdfs
    plugins: true // this will enable you to use pdfs as source and not just download it.
  }
});
```

*hint: without `webPreferences: { plugins: true }` your source PDF will be downloaded instead of loaded into the window.*

That said you will load your PDF into the `webContents` of your window. So we have to listen on events compatible with `BrowserWindow`. You did everything right, the only part you missed was that printing is another interface.

Printing will capture your `webContents` as it is when you press "print". This is very inportant to know when working with printers. Because if something will load slightly longer on a different system, for example the PDFs viewer will be still dark grey without the letters, then your printing will print the dark grey background or even the buttons.

That little issue is easily fixed with `setTimeout()`.

Useful Q&A for printing with electron:

- [Silent printing in electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46012272/silent-printing-in-electron/46020931#46020931)
- [Print: How to stick footer on every page to the bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42505164/print-how-to-stick-footer-on-every-page-to-the-bottom/42506373#42506373)

However there are alot more possible issues with printing, since most of the code is behind closed doors without worldwide APIs to use. Just keep in mind that every printer can behave differently so testing on more machines will help.

Comment: Thanks, please check my cross-comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46012272/silent-printing-in-electron/46020931?noredirect=1#comment90809378_46020931).

Comment: @Noseratio have you tried this repository? github.com/gerhardberger/electron-pdf-window You are right as long as you try to print normally you can't set the options.

Comment: Thanks, haven't come across it, it's a useful resource indeed and it also uses PDF.JS so good for previewing but not so much for printing. So I guess it will be a combo of PDF.JS (UI) and PDFium (backend).

Answer (score 3):

This is 2021 and here is the simplest way ever.

Let's begin

First of all, install the pdftoprinter

```
npm install --save pdf-to-printer
```

import the library into your file

```
const ptp require('pdf-to-printer') // something like this
```

Then call the method into your function

```
ptp.print('specify your route/url');
```

It should work!

Comment: The method is not yet implemented for win32

Comment: yes this one resolve my problem. my code for silent print is "ptp.print(filepath2, {silent: true}).then(console.log);"

Answer (score 2):

So it seems like you're trying to download the pdf file rather than print a pdf of the current screen which is what `print` tries to do. As such, you have a couple of options.

**1) Disable the native pdf viewer in electron:**

If you don't care about the electron window displaying the pdf, disabling the native pdf viewer in electron should instead cause it to treat the file as a download and attempt to download it.

```
new BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: {
    plugins: false
  }
})
```

You may also want to checkout [electron's DownloadItem api](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/download-item) to do some manipulation on where the file  will be saved.

**2) Download the pdf through some other api**

I'm not gonna give any specifics for this one because you should be able to find some information on this yourself, but basically if you want to download the file from somewhere, then you can use some other download API like an AJAX library to download the file and save it somewhere. This would potentially allow you to render the document in an electron window as well, since once you initiate the download you can probably redirect the window to the pdf url and have the native viewer handle it.

Long story short, it sounds to me like you don't really want to print from electron, you just want to save the pdf file that you're displaying. Printing from electron will render what you see on the screen, not the pdf document itself so I think you just misunderstood what the goal of print was. Hopefully this helps you, good luck!

=== EDIT ===

Unfortunately, I don't believe that there is a way to print the file directly from electron since electron printing is for printing the contents of electrons display. But you should be able to download the file via a simple request for the file (see above).

My recommendation for you would be to create a page for previewing the file. This would be an independent page, not the built in pdf viewer. You can then insert a button somewhere on the page to download the pdf via some means and skip any save location prompts (this should be easy enough to find documentation for).

Then, in order to have your preview, on the same page you can have a [`webview` tag](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag) into your page, which will display the native pdf viewer. In order for the native pdf viewer to work in the webview tag, you *must* include the `plugins` attribute in the tag. It's a boolean tag, so it's mere presence is all that is needed such as `<webview ... plugins>` This turns on plugin support for that webview's renderer which is required for the pdf viewer.

You can modify the size styling of this tag on the page as you wish to suit your needs. A trick to get rid of the download and print options so that a user cannot press them is to append `#toolbar=0` to the end of the pdf url to prevent the native pdf viewer from displaying the top toolbar with these buttons.

So, this way you can have your preview, ensure that the user can't use the built in download or print from the pdf viewer with the extra ui, and you can add another button to download it so it can be printed later.

Comment: Actually, I do want to print directly from Electron, i.e. having a paper print-out is what I need. Downloading and printing it outside Electron is also an option if you can suggest an API or tool for printing a PDF, but please make sure it hasn't been covered by existing answers/comments.

Comment: @Noseratio So are you trying to print a pdf of non-pdf content, or print a pdf file from some source?

Comment: I want to preview and print a PDF file (having its URL). In its current version, Electon does the preview job, but fails to print it.

Comment: Hmm... that does complicate things a bit. So as I said, you're probably going to have to download the file before printing it bar some library that I'm not familiar with that can print the pdf directly from a url. Printing from electron is like printing from a web browser: it prints the web page, where as you want to print the pdf file. I'll update my answer with my suggestions for you.

Comment: `#toolbar=0`  etc.. that works for HTML but doesn't work for PDF, it only prints the current view (a single page) even if you hide the UI. Or maybe we're missing something. In which case, could you post a version that works correctly, taking [the OP's code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49650784/1768303) as  base? Thanks.

Comment: What I'm saying is you can't use electrons print to print the PDF right now. You will have to download the PDF file separately aside from the previewing. The `toolbar=0` is just to prevent the user from downloading through the PDF viewer that serves as a preview in the webview